# Catching NullPointerException at the end of if-else

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Let's say I have this if-else statement:

```
        if (isAdd()) {
            return addStatement();
        } else if (isChange()) {
            return chgStatement();
        } else if (isDelete()) {
            return delStatement();
        } else return null;
```

I want to wrap this in a try-catch statement, but I want to catch the null. How would I do this? I attempted:

```
    try{
        if (isAdd()) {
            return addStatement();
        } else if (isChange()) {
            return chgStatement();
        } else if (isDelete()) {
            return delStatement();
        } else return null;
    } catch(NullPointerException e){
        log.error("null!");
    }

    return null;
```

My problem is that I never want to hit the `else return null`, but I need to check `else if(isDelete())` rather than just `else return delStatement();`

Comment: For dealing with null pointer exceptions consider `Optional<>` . It was designed to be return type of methods that may return null value.

Comment: Never, **NEVER** catch a NPE. Instead do a simple null check in your if block.

Comment: which null are you trying to catch here? the 'return null' does NOT throw a NullPointerException, as you seem to be inplying

Comment: For your reading pleasure: [Google search on this site on catching a NPE](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+catch+a+nullpointerexception)

Comment: `return null` does not cause a NullPointer so nothing to catch here. It is quite unclear on what you want to do and why.

Comment: I think the answer you want is to replace 'return null' with 'throw new UsefulExceptionHere'